# How could we use a password which is not stored anywhere for accessing DB

Tags: php, security

I've searched and found some solution for DB password here and the claimed "popular" solution is to store a configuration file (0644) in local then required in PHP file.

But I wonder whethre or not there is a solution that we dont need to store the plain text in anywhere. We write a php file who is in charge of the management of DB, then every time we need access it, this php file is called and controlle the access of DB.

we only type a predefined password one time when we start up our web server then delete it from the memory. then this php file cut off the connection regularly with a newly generated password coming from the first one with AES-128 algo.

Am i talking about something impossible? How could we enhence the security ?

Comment: Rather 600 I would say.

Comment: This is a very interesting question but I would say it is much more suitable for **http://serverfault.com/** because this sounds like a core PHP or Apache mod but that's just my guess. PHP is designed to be used in a stateless environment and what you are requesting sounds much more suited for a stateful environment.

Comment: Maybe this? http://search.cpan.org/~phred/Apache-DBI-1.12/lib/Apache/DBI.pm

Comment: What’s wrong with storing it in a configuration file? I mean, you would normally apply [defense in depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_\(computing\)) and allow access to the database on from the web server. So if the password gets leaked somehow, it would be worthless. Unless the attacker can execute arbitrary code/commands in behalf of the web server. But in that case your solution would also fail.

Comment: And this? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/coggeshall-persist-084844.html

Comment: @Gunbo Because I know nothing about hack technique, I feel insecure to store plain text in somewhere connected to the internet. But i will look at what you suggest to see whether or not it is already enough.Thanks!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thanks for your link, I would try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use sessions to maintain passwords, as they are not stored in the client side if i'm not wrong.

Comment: In fact I prefer not to store them anywhere, neither client side nor server side cause I know nothing about hack technique, perhaps they can hack into server computer and decode the password and ruin everything.